# How to dynamically allocate block of text using css?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic and trying to do something like this:[image]

I'm using css and as you can see, it works, but when the text length is different, things get weird:
[image]

this is the css I'm using:

```
.block-with-text {
  /* hide text if it more than N lines  */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* for set '...' in absolute position */
  position: relative;
  /* use this value to count block height */
  line-height: 1.2em;
  /* max-height = line-height (1.2) * lines max number (3) */
  max-height: 3.6em;
  /* fix problem when last visible word doesn't adjoin right side  */
  text-align: justify;
  /* place for '...' */
  margin-right: -1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

and my html

```
        <div class="row">
          <div class="padding">
            <img src="img/san-francisco.jpg" style="width: 80px; height: 80px; border-radius:5px;" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="">
            <div class="news-header block-with-text">
              <h2>{{new.title}}</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="news-summary block-with-text">
              <p>
                {{new.summary}}
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="row news-footer">
              <div>
                {{new.tags[0]}}
              </div>
              <div>
                {{new.source}}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I want to make the bottom text limit to 2 lines of text if header is 3 lines, if header is 2 I want to have it 3 lines, any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Yeah, good luck in trying to control text justification.

Comment: You can't do that with css only. You need javascript or jquery to check the height of your title and resize the paragraph accordingly.

Comment: @ospfranco try to use ellipsis

Comment: @miro that is what I was afraid of, do you have an angular snippet I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @daniel beck comment on his answer, I got something that works:
[image]
[image]

it is not perfect, header and text size have to be the same and spacing must be the same as well, still, only made some minor modifications to css:

```
.block-with-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.2em;

  /* changed this to hold 5 lines */
  max-height: 5em;

  text-align: justify;
  margin-right: -1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

and html:

```
            <div class="block-with-text">
              <div class="news-header ">
                <h2>{{new.title}}</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="news-summary">
                <p>
                  {{new.summary}}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make the bottom text limit to 2 lines of text if header is 3 lines, if header is 2 I want to have it 3 lines

Editing this answer to add that under specific circumstances -- both header and body have the same line-height -- this can be done in pure CSS by wrapping both the header and body text in a box five lines tall, with `overflow:hidden`:

```css
.row {
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border: 1px solid
}

.news-header {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="news-header">This head will be two lines long. This head will be two lines long.</div>
  <div class="news-summary">body text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body text</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="news-header">This head will be three lines long. This head will be three lines long. This head will be three lines long.</div>
  <div class="news-summary">body text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body text</div>
</div>
```

That won't be suitable for most layouts; anything more complex moves you out of pure CSS territory and into javascript.  I don't recommend this, it's fragile enough that it probably warrants a redesign, but:

```js
// depending on jQuery here, obviously.  Put this somewhere that it will run after the regular DOM layout has completed.
$('.news-header').each(function() {
  var LINEHEIGHT=22; // in px.  Adjust as needed to match your css
  if ($(this).height() === (LINEHEIGHT*2)) {
    $(this).next('.news-summary').height(LINEHEIGHT*3);
  } else {
    $(this).next('.news-summary').height(LINEHEIGHT*2);
  };
  // note conspicuous failure to handle 4-line, 1-line, etc headers
});
```

```css
.row {
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.news-header {font-weight: bold;}
.news-summary {overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="news-header">This head will be two lines long. This head will be two lines long.</div>
  <div class="news-summary">body text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body text</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="news-header">This head will be three lines long. This head will be three lines long. This head will be three lines long.</div>
  <div class="news-summary">body text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body textbody text body text</div>
</div>
```

The idea is to let the headline lay out normally, measure its height, then use that as a basis to set the height of the body text. This will only work if you have a set line height for both the headline and body -- here it doesn't have to be the same line height for both, but you'd need to account for any difference between the two in the calculation.

Comment: yes, everyone else agrees this is not really possible using css only, thanks for the js answer!

Comment: Oh god, having written that all out I just realized you *can* do it in pure CSS, in some specific circumstances -- if your headline and body text have the same line height, you could just put them both inside an overflow-hidden wrapper element with a fixed height of 5 lines...

Comment: Sure thing.  Can't believe I didn't think of that in the first place...!

Answer (score 0):

I think at first we should desire - what exactly should happens when text is too long? what exactly you waiting for in this case?

but I think you should remove `text-align:justify` or make it `text-align:left`

Comment: I think you can do it only programmatically, using js code, for example,
you should calculate text length and according to that lenght change max-height of text block - that`s the idea what I got for now

Comment: already tried that, doesn't really work, it depends on the rendering of the font on device and the chars used, for example: "aaabbc" doesn't have the same length as "iiillc" even though they are the same amount of chars.

Comment: oh, you right, and I have another idea
as I understand text block`s positioned using relative or absolute properties
It`s not good, so my idea is make it without position:relative, just let text block`s lie as they are, one under one, set to title fixed height as it should be for 3 text rows, and set height for bottom text block for 2 text rows, so it would be always 3 rows for top and 2 for bottom... or do not set fixed height for parent block...